# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.4.0.0

Tags: c#

First of, some context information:

The platform this is running on has .Net Framework 4.7.1 installed. I have a Class Library that is in the .Net Standard 2 specification in order to support .Net Core in the future. Now parts of dependencies, namely Dapper, uses System.Data.SqlClient. This library works just fine on my own machine but I run into problems when I deploy and test it on my Windows 2012 server. Namely, I have a runtime error when Dapper is used: `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=kfddsnfsjnfs' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Mind you I first had version 4.5.1.0 installed. I then downgraded to 4.4.0.0 and rerrun the code. Now I got the same error but this time regarding 4.2.0.0. But I cannot seem to find this particular version on Nuget. After this I googled. A lot. First I tried adding rebindining the old version with a new by adding both a

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "dependentAssembly": {
    "assemblyIdentity": {
      "name": "System.Data.SqlClient",
      "publicKeyToken": "kfddsnfsjnfs",
      "culture": "neutral"
    },
    "bindingRedirect": {
      "oldVersion ": "4.4.0.0",
      "newVersion": "4.5.1"
    }
  }
}
```

and app.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SqlClient"  publicKeyToken="kfddsnfsjnfs"  culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.4.0.0" newVersion="4.5.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

However it didn't make a difference. I have also tried older versions of the SqlClient and multiple reinstalls. I also found people who said to double check the csproj file so it didn't reference something in the gac, but it does not:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <Authors>me</Authors>
    <Product />
    <Company />
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>false</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Version>1.0.8</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="TaskMetadata.json">
      <PackagePath>TaskMetadata.json</PackagePath>
      <Pack>True</Pack>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="dapper" Version="1.50.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="itextsharp" Version="5.5.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.5.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="External\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Assuming that this a Visual Studio project, have you checked the references in the References node?

Comment: Yes, I actually have two references to SqlClient both on Dependencies>Nuget>Dapper>System.Data.SQLClient and Dependencies>Nuget>System.Data.SQLClient. They are both 4.5.1

Comment: in the folder where this program's executable is, do you see a `System.Data.SQLClient.dll` file on both your machine and the Windows 2012 server?

Comment: No, the closest DLL I can find is named System.Data.SQLite

Comment: go to the References node, then to *Add Reference...*, and then scroll down until you find `System.Data.SQLClient`.  click the checkbox next to it and then close the references window.  you should now have the correct DLL in the aforementioned folder after building your project.

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't *actually* use this public key token `kfddsnfsjnfs`?

Comment: Under Add references there are none to add. Only under COM category but there is none called system.data.sqlclient.  Yes that public key is just a dummy value I picked for this post.

Comment: I've tried just downloading the nuget package for System.Data.SqlClient and adding manually, didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 50):

Each library runs under the process of the main application. So the main application needs to know to load the SqlClient DLL. So the parent project (the .NET 4.7.1 project) needs to have SqlClient added as a reference, either by installing the NuGet package, or just adding a reference by browsing to the DLL under the .NET Standard project.

*Old answer:* That version exists in NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/4.4.0

In the Package Manager Console (make sure the 'Default project' drop-down is set to the right one), try uninstalling and then reinstalling that specific version:

```
Uninstall-Package System.Data.SqlClient
Install-Package System.Data.SqlClient -Version 4.4.0
```

*Update:* Or, in your binding redirect, just use `4.2.0.0` as the `oldVersion`.

Comment: Importantly if you update the version in your standard project you need to also update the version in your framework project or you may wind up distributing the wrong file.

Answer (score 11):

install version 4.8.2 in both project

Install-Package System.Data.SqlClient -Version 4.8.2

Comment: It really worked but I don't know why we must install to both project

Answer (score 10):

Switch from `System.Data.SqlClient` to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/

Comment: What version of .net core are you using? Oddly enough it was working perfectly for me in 3.0 but as soon as I updated to 3.1 I started getting this error.

Comment: i don't remember, but core 3.x wasn't in use by our team yet

Comment: I am having this problem with .net core version 3.1 as well. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Did you say `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, perhaps?

Comment: We have a .Net Framework 4.6.1 assembly and included it on a .Net Core 3.1 api, so we needed to include 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient' on both, the library and the main api project. 
Change code from Systems.Data.SqlClient to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient Also require to add this line at Startup constructor:

`public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;

    // Chesare. Requerido para .net Core
    DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("Microsoft.Data.SqlClient", Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory.Instance);
}`

Comment: see related ['The specified invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' wasn't found in the list of registered .NET Data Providers.' on a .netCore project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62254882/the-specified-invariant-name-system-data-sqlclient-wasnt-found-in-the-list-o)

Comment: This worked, and you can actually see that it's an assembly for .NET.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, Basically I was developing a win form app. with .net framework, and my class library was .net standard.

I tried install and uninstall `System.Data.SqlClient ten times`, it did not work

Then something later crossed my mind as I installed same reference in the UI layer as well then it worked. even though, I did not have any code talking to Sql on UI layer, then another issue raised as the UI did not recognize reference to Dapper as well, and I had to install Dapper reference on UI too. Then everything was fine.

I really surprises how that did not work. Once you referenced the UI to the class library, the class library supposed to do what is required and pass the data to UI!!

Comment: Same issue here when I moved a solution to a new folder on .net core 6.0. The project for the UI layer did not have System.Data.Sql.Client installed and did not need it, but it was looking for version 4.6. when it called the DLL on the database layer. Installing the current 4.8 version of System.Data.Sql.Client on the UI project via nuget, even though it never used it, fixed the problem .

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `System.Data.SqlClient` again via NuGet although you may already have it handy as a part of the .NET Framework. This solution resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue while running unit test cases. `{"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.":"System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"}   System.IO.FileNotFoundException`

When I install System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.4.0.0 then it did not work.

**But this got fixed when I installed the latest version of System.Data.SqlClient nuget package.**

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error at the console in one of my webjobs in Azure. In the publish profile I changed configuration from "debug" to "release" and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error with .NET Core (using the latest `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`) and had to change my DBProvider from

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
```

to

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
```

in order for NLog to load `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`