# 'The specified invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' wasn't found in the list of registered .NET Data Providers.' on a .netCore project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am getting the error above on a .netCore API project that's referencing .netCore library that connects to a SQL database. Can anyone help me here?
I have already referenced the System.Data.SQLClient or Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and still no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 37):

There is no global configuration (commonly known as GAC) in .NET Core. As a result, the provider is not registered by default. You will have to manually register the provider. You can register it as

```
DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("System.Data.SqlClient", System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory.Instance);

//for Connection
var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");
DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
```

Comment: Thanks. How about if the library was build in .net framework? is the a 'DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory()' for a .net framework or it's equivalent?

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but the library might search in `machine.config`. If you want to overwrite the `DbProviderFactories`, then you might have to update your `app.config` file. Something like  `<system.data> <DbProviderFactories> <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" /> <add name="SqlClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Providerfor SqlServer" type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" /> </DbProviderFactories> </system.data>`

Comment: We have a .Net Framework 4.6.1 assembly and included it on a .Net Core 3.1 api, so we needed to include 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient' on both, the library and the main api project. 
Change code from Systems.Data.SqlClient to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient Also require to add this line at Startup constructor:

`public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;

    // Chesare. Requerido para .net Core
    DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("Microsoft.Data.SqlClient", Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory.Instance);
}`

Comment: see [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53159316/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlclient-version-4-4-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

Just changing Systems.Data.SqlClient to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient in Nuget already worked for me