# The specified invariant name 'System.Data.sqlClient' wasn't found in the list of registered .NET data providers in an ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing ASP.NET Core Web API for an ASP.NET MVC project. So, all services are written based on MVC and I should only call them, however, I come across the above error. I have tried the below codes, unfortunately, none of them worked.

I used `RegisterFactory` in the `Configure` method of the `Startup` class to add the `invariantName`:

```
DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("System.Data.SqlClient", System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory.Instance);
```

I then added the provider to `appsetting.json`:

```
"entityFramework": {
    "providers": {
        "provider": {
            "invariantName": "System.Data.SqlClient",
            "type": "System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"
        }
    }
}
```

Some additional information:

1. The .NET Core version is 2.2
2. The EF version is 6.0.0
3. The `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` version is 3.1.20

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps manually register it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62254882/the-specified-invariant-name-system-data-sqlclient-wasnt-found-in-the-list-o

Comment: @jspcal yes, as I mentioned in the question, I tried the manual registeration method but it did not work.

Comment: @mason I changed it but I get the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore some EntityFrameworkCorenuget packages to 2.0.0.

It seems to have solved this problem for me.

These are the packages I downgraded:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
```