# Can't Load Service-Based Database in VB.NET?

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, sqlconnection

I don't know why can't I load this service-based database in my project.

I just downloaded the community version with following packages:

[image]

I have nothing loaded anything except a default form, and I try to add database:

[image]

And this is the error I'm getting:

[image]

And also I can't find app.config file, I saw that we have to change some code to fix this error.

> Error Message: Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version-5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublickeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5' or one of its dependencies, The
> system cannot find the file specified.

I was expecting it to load table in my project

Comment: Please add the error as text.

Comment: have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53159316/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlclient-version-4-4-0-0 ?

Comment: Sounds like at least one package may not have been installed properly. I would suggest trying a repair of VS.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version-5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublickeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5' or one of its dependencies, The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Will try it soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can try manually installing Microsoft.Data.SqlClient from Nuget Package Manager.
[image]